# CAST for Format() a DateTime to Date on both SQL Server and MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, datetime

I have an application that can use either SQL Server or MS Access as the data store.

In one table, I have a DATETIME column.  I would like to retrieve the value as a DATE value (with the time part stripped off).

I can do that in SQLServer with CAST() and in MS Access with Format().  Ideally, I would like a single SQL query that could be applied against either database instead of sending a slightly different query to each database.  Does anyone know a trick to do this?

Comment: 2008, although a solution encompassing as many possible versions would be ideal.

Comment: Does something like CONVERT(DATE, [DATE_STRING], 103) not work?  Where '103' is the format you wish to convert into?

Comment: No, CONVERT — like CAST — is SQL Server only (I'm pretty sure, but I'll run a test to confirm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DATEADD/DATEDIFF

Sql Server

```
SELECT DATEADD("d",  DATEDIFF("d", 0, getdate()), 0) as someDateOnly
```

MS Access

```
SELECT DATEADD("d",  DATEDIFF("d", 0, Now()),0) AS someDateOnly;
```

Just use a field name in place of `GetDate()` and `Now()`

E.g.

```
 SELECT DATEADD("d",  DATEDIFF("d", 0, [somefield]),0) AS someDateOnly;
```

as an aside DateAdd/DateDiff is the way you want to go if you want to strip the time in versions prior to 2008 anyway.

Comment: Perfect.  You don't happen to know a similar trick for an interoperable COALESCE / IFNULL / NZ function?

Comment: But in this case you still have a different syntax! GetDate() and Now() means you have to handle it in your code, so have any type of DDL.

Comment: @Yves, the GetDate and Now were just for example.  The last SELECT, that actually uses a column name, is the one I can use for both databases.

Comment: I find that in SQL Server this returns `2011-10-27 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you run access (e.g. in development) and sometimes a sql server and you want to make sure it works in both?

There are only two way I know (which don't pretend to be final :)).

- create all selects as queries either in your sql or access database.
  Then in your code you access the queries only
- develop a database layer where you statements will be parsed and
  handle each database.

Since the syntax is different there is no other way I know...

Comment: No, this application is supporting several clients, some running Access and some SQL Server.  I'm already using separate DDL for the two databases when updates are required, so I could adapt the first technique to create VIEWs for each situation in which I have to use product specific functions like this.

Comment: Well the views only work if you don't have to cast/convert your queries with where statements. In this case you have to collect all data and filter them in your client application. This overload the data and is against the idea of it I guess. So if you already have a DDL I think you have your goal already reached. Better, but not always possible, is to you an abstraction layer like moderm frameworks do (e.g. RoR Active record). But this don't fix your problem also if you really have to access the data due a specific select statement.